# Azure Devops Extension Loading Fails due to connect-src issue

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to add [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=palacino-gio.marked-mermaid-renderer) to my azure devops organization. However, when I try to install this extension and then view a repo's README I am met with the following error

```
`Refused to connect to 'https://browser.events.data.microsoft.com/OneCollector/1.0/?cors=true&content-type=application/x-json-stream&client-id=NO_AUTH&client-version=1DS-Web-JS-3.1.11&apikey=<not sure if sensitive info so hiding this for now>&upload-time=1663224261051&w=0' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src ...`
```

I generally understand the error seems to be telling me that the extension is trying to access SOMETHING (not entirely sure what) that originates outside the accepted domains listed after the string `connect-src`.

I tried perusing through my organization settings to see if there was a way to modify the CSP that way to no avail. I do know that the extension itself [see the github here](https://github.com/GioCirque/vsts-extensions/tree/main/mermaid) calls upon a few scripts. For reference, I forked this repo and tried to publish it on my own with a few tweaks which were as follows:

- I changed the publisher name to my own vs extensions publisher name
- I changed references to render.js to render.ts (there is no render.js file and was getting a 404 not found for render.js before I did this)

I tried clicking on the link that was being attempted to be accessed but was met with an error stating that this route does not accept GET requests (I sort of figured this would be the case but worth a shot)

I guess my questions are as follows

- Is there a way to update the CSP for my individual org in AzDo?
- If not, is there a way to work around this pesky error?

#### Update

Figured I should include some of the connect-src's that AzureDevOps would accept

- .visualstudio.com
- wss://*.visualstudio.com
- https://web.vortex.data.microsoft.com
- *.dev.azure.com

#### Update 2

The following is the case when I leave reference to `scripts/render.js as is

```
GET https://baselanani.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/BaselAnani/extension/markedmermaidv2/0.0.4/assetbyname/scripts/render.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Comment: Don't just renamen a `.ts` file. They need to be transpiled to Javascript.

Comment: no no I didn't rename a `.ts` file. There was a couple `<script>` tag referencing `render.js`

Comment: Yeah, they should refernece the `js` file. The extension is supposed to be packaged using webpack, which will take care of the Typescript -> Javascript transpilation.

Comment: `<script src="scripts/render.js"></script>` here though there is no `scripts/render.js` there was only `scripts/render.ts`

Comment: I do have a webpackconfig file and yes the output there is `render.js` but for that specific script there is no `scripts/render.js`

Comment: see update for when I revert this back to render.js

Comment: I suspect the error you see in the log is unrelated to why the extension won't load.

Comment: Azure DevOps now also has built-in partial mermaid support. What I'm guessing is that the built-in mermaid support is taking precedence and that that's why the extension won't load.

Comment: I don’t think this is the case that they are giving precedence to their own mermaid support. It is available only in wiki we are trying to extend for .md files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension loads just fine in my environment when opening markdown files in Repositories. I see the error message in my browser console as well. They seem to be unrelated:

[image: Extension working just fine]

[image: Error message in the console]

Comment: hmm interesting thanks for that feedback I'll keep digging for it

Comment: after some further digging, the extension in the marketplace works just fine, we wanted to clone the repo so that we could extend it. The error as you mention is unrelated so thanks for that, but for some reason publishing from that repo does not work (removed unsupported svg files before publishing)